# How to save trainset's distribution on a trained LDA models by gensim?

Tags: python, lda, gensim

last parts of the code:

```
lda = models.LdaModel(corpus_tfidf, id2word = dic, num_topics = 64)
corpus_lda = lda[corpus_tfidf]
```

I am wondering how to save corpus_lda for further use?

Comment: Do you mean you want to save the `lda` model? I'm asking because your code makes `corpus_lda` contain the topic distributions per training document.

Comment: I know corpus_lda contain the topic distributions , that's what I want to save, I want to save the distributions as a 2173*64(2173 is my training documents number and 64 is the topics) matrix, but don't know how to save it.

Comment: A fast solution would be to use the [cPickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle) module and dump the topic distribution matrix into a file, and then use the same module to load the matrix whenever you want to use it.

Comment: Thank you very much! @Lord Henry Wotton

Answer (score 2):

Gensim has functions for writing corpora to disk:

```
from Gensim import corpora
corpora.MmCorpus.serialize('pathandfilename.mm', corpus_lda)
```

To load a saved corpus use:

```
corpus_lda = corpora.MmCorpus('pathandfilename.mm')
```

There are similar functions for saving models (check the tutorials or the [references](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/apiref.html)). 
There are different corpus formats available, I believe matrix market used to be the standard format used by Gensim but recently the indexedcorpus format was added, which has some additional functionality (an index, as you may have guessed).